# How to browser cache image from php

Tags: joomla, browser-cache, virtuemart

I use virtuemart. There are a lot of images about the products. But this images come from a php file(imgtag.php), so I can't force the browser with this code to take the product images to the cache:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|ttf|eot|swf)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>
```

Example for product image URL:

http://www.myshop.com/components/com_virtuemart/show_image_in_imgtag.php?filename=be6160cc3ede6b58d13f4adaa61f49f7.jpg&newxsize=120&newysize=120&fileout=

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your `imgtag.php` file, so it sends that header, using the PHP [**`header()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function :

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=2592000');
```

*Note : setting headers must be done before any output.*

Comment: this will cache only html of requested page

Comment: This will cache the data that's returned by imgtag.php -- if that data is an image, the header will be on that image ; and it'll get cached.